# I am using codeigniter i need to optimize the search query using joining

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for an application where search needs to be performed i am using "Like" in the query for two tables. One table has data while other table has translations of it. So i need to search the string from both tables to get the result. Following is my query can any body make it more efficient. both tables has almost 10k records which may increase in future. If i am not joining the table then it works faster but with joining it takes long to give the results.

```
        $this->db->select('tbl2.translation_title as title,tbl1.id,tbl1.title as title');
        $this->db->like('tbl1.title',$searchString);
        $this->db->or_like('tbl2.translation_title',$searchString);
        $this->db->join('tbl2', 'tbl1.id = tbl2.item_id', 'left');
        $this->db->group_by('tbl1.id');
        $this->db->limit('25');
        $res = $this->db->get('tbl1')->result();
```

Comment: May i know the reasons why i am getting down vote for this question.

Comment: Check your indicies (is item_id indexed?). 10k per table is nothing. Also, what is `$query`?

Comment: Can you please guide me in brief about how can i check indexes?

Comment: $query is the search string which is being passed.

Comment: Yes, but what's the _value_ of it.

Comment: It can be anything as string for example "ipad"

Comment: I'm not "up" on CI stuff. Apparently `like()` does an open ended '%value%' check, so that fouls up that using indicies....

Comment: you can provide me alternative of it in simple mysql query i will change it to CI what changes you think needs to be performed in query if i am writing query in non CI way.

Comment: To be honest, other than checking that `item_id` has an index on it, there's limited "quick wins" for this, especially if you need the search to match anywhere in the column value. It _might_ be worth doing some reading up on full text search, but I'm not sure how much of a performance difference it will make given the table sizes.

Comment: Btw, asking people to do things for you is probably the reason for the downvotes. It gives a bad impression that you're not willing to do things yourself.

Comment: @JonStirling Thanks for your explanation its clear now. Also i would be careful next time in my question. But my intentions were not to get it 100% resolved by someone else. I was just looking for a hint. Thanks

Comment: Your alias `table` belongs to 2 columns. Also, your query contains `LEFT JOIN` and `LIKE`. These probably are the reason that make your query slow. Think again if they're necessary or not. Ways that I optimize my database is use `FROM tbl1, tbl2 WHERE tbl1.id = tbl2.item_id` instead of `JOIN`, and avoid to use `LIKE` to prevent the server scans the whole table.

Comment: @Benyi thanks for your valuable suggestion i would definitely think about it. I am using LIKE to compare the string as we usually do for searching function in a website. If you have any other suggestion which i can use instead of LIKE to achieve the results would be highly appreciated.